# Background image transition not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have set the transition CSS property for a hover effect but for some reason it isn't working.

HTML-

```
<div class = "menuItemBox" id = "Mughlai">
    <p class = "menuItemHeading">Mughlai</p> 
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.menuItemBox {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: DC3D00;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 33%;
    height: 180px;
    background-size: cover;
}

#Mughlai {
    background-image: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#Mughlai:hover {
    background-image: url("./images/Mughlai.jpg");
}
```

Comment: And with `#Mughlai:hover{...}` ?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to paste a piece of my CSS. Let me edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Add hover to #Mughlai.**

```css
.menuItemBox {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: DC3D00;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 33%;
    height: 180px;
    background-size: cover;
   transition: 0.3s;
}

#Mughlai:hover {
    background-image: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
   border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class = "menuItemBox" id = "Mughlai">
    <p class = "menuItemHeading">Mughlai</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to paste a piece of my CSS. Let me edit my question.